# I encountered this hosting error when deploying Angular project to Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, error-handling, deployment, hosting

I successfuly deployed and hosted an angular project on firebase, however when I do **ng serve** and i go to the localhost:4200 i find a blank page with a error in the console containing this :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMm9Y.png)
(caught FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options).)

also when I visit the website where the app is deployed i get no error message but the app doesn't show up.

**I have initilized firebase like so : **

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ChatFormComponent } from './chat-form/chat-form.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideAuth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideDatabase, getDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {  AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { ChatService } from './services/chat.service';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ChatFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideDatabase(() => getDatabase())
  ],
  providers: [ChatService, AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**and this is my environment.ts file**

```
export const environment = {

  production: false,
  firebaseConfig : {
  apiKey: "//hidden_info",
  authDomain: "//hidden_info",
  databaseURL: "//hidden_info",
  projectId: "//hidden_info",
  storageBucket: "//hidden_info",
  messagingSenderId: "//hidden_info",
  appId: "//hidden_info"
},
firebase : {
  apiKey: "//hidden_info",
  authDomain: "//hidden_info",
  databaseURL: "//hidden_info",
  projectId: "//hidden_info",
  storageBucket: "//hidden_info",
  messagingSenderId: "//hidden_info",
  appId: "//hidden_info"
}
};
```

**this is firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/client",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]

  },
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  }

}
```

**and these are my dependencies**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "firebase": "^9.21.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you fixed this?